# How do I keep text and an iframe on the same line when resizing in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am really stuck here. As soon as I try to reduce the size of my page, the iframe goes on to the next line. The text next to the iframe doesn't wrap around the image. I do not want the iframe to move below the paragraph when resizing. I am using bootstrap 3. Here is my code. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? As I am new to coding please let me know exactly what I need to do. Thanks.

```css
.video-feature p {
    text-align: justify;
}

.video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    
}

.video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 374px;
    max-height: 210px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="video-feature">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h2>Ji-Sung Park becomes an ambassador</h2>
                    <p>Massa Ipsum Feugiat Massa Semper Bibendum Sagittis Convallis Porttitor donec mi lorem. Nulla morbi hymenaeos habitant, maecenas hymenaeos luctus ullamcorper ligula arcu congue curabitur malesuada fusce justo facilisi. Odio eu facilisi magnis porta condimentum. Integer facilisi odio. Vivamus dui pretium Fringilla tempus vulputate odio.Mattis ut lorem viverra magnis auctor praesent elit sociis habitasse placerat tempus dapibus. Nunc, varius adipiscing est donec neque est sed fusce luctus primis</p>
                </div>       
                <div class="col-md-5">
                <br>
                    <div class="video">
                        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3Q9qf7xzw4Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: don't think your snippet represents your situation very well, suggest you try to set it up in http://www.bootply.com/new...

Answer (score 2):

Just add `col-sm-7` and `col-sm-5` to your divs, respectively, as this takes care of keeping the same layout on smaller (hence the `sm`) screens.

So your new code would look like this:

```
<div class="video-feature">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                <h2>Ji-Sung Park becomes an ambassador</h2>
                <p>Massa Ipsum Feugiat Massa Semper Bibendum Sagittis Convallis Porttitor donec mi lorem. Nulla morbi hymenaeos habitant, maecenas hymenaeos luctus ullamcorper ligula arcu congue curabitur malesuada fusce justo facilisi. Odio eu facilisi magnis porta condimentum. Integer facilisi odio. Vivamus dui pretium Fringilla tempus vulputate odio.Mattis ut lorem viverra magnis auctor praesent elit sociis habitasse placerat tempus dapibus. Nunc, varius adipiscing est donec neque est sed fusce luctus primis</p>
            </div>       
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
            <br>
                <div class="video">
                    video
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo you can play with: http://www.bootply.com/PaOzjKC8yN (note that, for demonstration purposes, I removed the iframe as bootply doesn't allow it to display for some reason, replaced it with the word `video`).

Here is a link to the [Bootstrap documentation explaining the Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the video moves underneath the text when continuing to reduce the screen size. The sm option works for a bit, but when I continue to reduce the screen size, the problem still remains.

Comment: for that, you have `xs`... have you had a look at the documentation link i provided?

Comment: Besides using `xs` use the responsive embed classes. Read docs